# Grails Domain Object hasMany irregular behaviour using contains

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-orm

I'm having an issue where calling `.contains()` on one of my domain classes' `hasMany` relationships is not doing the same when running normally, or when debugging. The situation is as follows:

I have 2 domain objects, `A` and `B`. `A` has a `hasMany` relationship with `B`.

```
class A {
    ...
    static hasMany = [bees: B]
    ...
}
```

Now, during the execution of one of my filters, I grab my current user from the spring security service. This user also contains a single instance of `B`. What my filter should do is to check if the instance of `B` in the user is contained in some instance of `A`.

Assume that the instances of `B` are actually referring to the same object (since they are).

Now, the issue arises. Calling:

```
if (instanceOfA.bees.contains(user.instanceOfB)) {
    println 'success'
} else {
    println 'failure'
}
```

prints `failure` during normal (or debugging without stepping through the code) execution. However, if I put a break-point there, and step through the code, it correctly executes the `contains()` and prints `success`.

I have also implemented `equals`, `hashCode` and `compareTo` in an attempt to resolve this, but with the same behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it seems that using one of the Groovy transform annotations seems to do the trick. Simply adding:

```
// uid is a uniqe UUID we use to identify with other systems.
@EqualsAndHashCode(includes = ["id", "uid"])
```

does the trick. Seems a bit strange that the IDE generated methods (using the same fields) did not...

Answer (score 3):

This is usually due to lazyloading or cache. Use `instanceOfA.bees.id.contains(user.instanceOfB.id)` and it always works.

Comment: This looks like the answer closest to what I would have liked, but I think adding the `@EqualsAndHashCode` annotation makes the code more readable (since you can then call the `contains` method as one would expect). See my own answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Maybe your `user.instanceOfB` object is a hibernate proxy object and therefore not a *real* B. You can check this using a debugger or printing `user.instanceOfB.getClass()`.

You can use `GrailsHibernateUtil.unwrapIfProxy(proxyObject)` to get the real object from the proxy.

Answer (score 1):

I would do this with HQL:

```
A.executeQuery("select a from A a join a.bees as b where b = :b and a = :a", [a: instanceOfA, b: user.instanceOfB])
```